# AngularJS - accessing DOM element Attributes inside ng-If

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Is there a way to access the attributes of an HTML tag inside ng-If?

I currently have this but it doesn't seem to work.

PS: I set the attribute inside a directive.

```html
<button ng-if="angular.element(this).attr('attributeName')" class="btn"> Secure</button>
```

**Edit**

I want to add a button to the DOM if a condition is met but the condition is determined inside a directive which makes HTTP request to the server. I don't want the button displayed till a response is received from the server hence the ngIf and I'm thinking adding an attribute to the element once a response is received so the ngIf evaluates to true.

**Use case**

I'm editing an existing HTML and adding more restrictions based on user role. So for instance User role X should be able to click on a link to visit a secured page but Y should not even have to see there's a link to a secured page. I can't use ngShow/ngHide as they are already defined on the buttons and control entirely different conditions.

Any suggestions on how to implement this without creating a new directive (ideally)?

Comment: in that context, 'this' refers to the surrounding scope, not the element. I can't think of a great way to do this without creating a directive. Let me know if you want an example of that.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'm hoping I won't have to create a directive for this as there are so many buttons across different files needing this condition.

Comment: Do you always need to show one button for each HTTP request? In other words: will there be one HTTP request and on completion a number of buttons are shown, OR will there be many HTTP requests and each of them will show a button depending on the response?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<button ng-attr-name="{{condition}}" class="btn"> Secure</button>
```

and see the angular document

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Your suggestion would mean adding an attribute if a certain condition is met which is far different from what I want.

Comment: I want to add a button to the DOM if a condition is met but the condition is determined inside a directive which makes HTTP request to the server. I don't want the button displayed till a response is received from the server hence the ngIf and I'm thinking adding an attribute to the element once a response is received.